# How to install PVC J-Channel Brickmould?

Tags: installation, flashing

I'm looking to install this [Brickmould with J-Channel](https://www.menards.com/main/search.html?sf_categoryHierarchy=&search=brickmould+with+channel) when I reside my garage.

[image]

I've looked at a number of manufacturer install guides and they either skip over brickmoulding or do not address this particular version of brickmould with j-channel. I've also made many Google searches and have come up empty handed there too. All standard brickmould installation.

Many of the videos, tutorials, and installation instructions are like the [video that Kris has linked to in the comments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1MLEpg6TAY). It shows standard brickmould without the built-in J-Channel. I'm starting to assume that you treat it like normal brickmould due to the lack of installation instructions for this particular type of brickmould.

---

How should I flash the door with this type of brickmould? Flash rough opening with flex for the sill, flashing tap on the sides and header. Then nail the brickmould with j-channel on top? Maybe flash the nailing flang of the brickmould  after doing so?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1MLEpg6TAY

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've watched that video. It shows standard brickmould without the built-in J-Channel. Many of the videos, tutorials, and installation instructions are like that video. I'm starting to assume that you treat it like normal brickmould due to the lack of installation instructions for this particular type of brickmould.

Comment: Yes you install it the same also you would prepare the opening with standard flashing and waterproofing techniques.

Comment: So, more or less, flash etc. the rough opening, install jamb, install brickmould (on top of flashing, wrb? No extra prep like taping the flanges?

Comment: I am not sure if it is recommended to seal tape over the nail fins after installation or not